# Is there a way to disable specific keys in C#?

Tags: c#, function, xna

I am trying to make it so that when my character jumps the jump key is disabled until his jumpHeight == 0 (he is back on the floor). Is there an easy function in C# to be able to do this? For example:

```
if (jumpHeight > 0)
{
   keys.space == disabled
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend adding a "OnGround" property to your Player and set it to false when he's in the air. Then later on when you check the space key first check if OnGround = true. (Basically what AlexM said)

Answer (score 5):

Your approach means more pointless work, and won't allow you to *disable* the actual input anyway. Instead, you should choose to not perform any checks on the status of particular keys if a condition is met.

```
public void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    if (canCheckSpace)
    {
         if (spaceIsPressed())
         {
              doThings();
         }
    }
    if (jumpHeight > 0)
    {
        canCheckSpace = false;
    }
}
```

If you wish to "disable" a key for all of the scripts checking for it, consider wrapping the input into your own manager, that will check for those conditions and act accordingly, for any script calling its public methods.

Comment: Good answer, just be aware of where you declare the variable. You never set it to true.

Comment: I supposed it's a member of whatever class wrapped Update(GameTime), since I omitted the declaration.

Comment: Thanks for that, got it working now after messing around with the function for a while, Cheers